# When / where do I scroll my table view after initialization?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Here is the situation:

I have a table view that has a fixed number of rows, I want it to be scrolled to a specific row when it appears to the user (no animation). The position of the row is based on some calculations (ex: top of row must be 200px from top), so I can't use `scrollToRow`.

I tried to use `didMoveToSuperview` and set the `contentOffset` but layout hasn't happened yet so I don't know the offset yet (that 200px in the above example).

I could do the scrolling in `layoutSubviews` but that method is called a bunch of times and that seems inefficient.

Is there a better / good way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `didMoveToWindow`? Another func I think it work is `layoutSubviews`. It will be multiple times when each subView will be layout. By using a flag, you can use it.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if !didScrolling {
       didScrolling = true
       //do scrolling
    }
}
```

or

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    indexSubView += 1
    if indexSubView >= self.subviews.count {
       //do scrolling
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that will work because I am in a view, not a controller...

Comment: Thanks but I mentioned in my question that layoutSubviews is called a bunch of times, but I only want this to happen once

Comment: Yes, I know it is called a bunch of times. My mean is use it with trick to make sure scrolling only 1 times.